# What's an OR and AND decomposition in statechart diagrams?

Tags: uml, statechart

I was reading about statechart diagrams, which are diagrams that model the different states that one or more instances of one or more classes can be.

An object can go from one state to the other through a transition, which is represented using arrow with an event and eventually a action to that event over and respectively below it.

My problem now is that I don't understand exactly what are OR and AND decompositions in a statechart diagram. Could you please give me an explanation (since I've not found around any)?

I would really appreciate a concrete example with the corresponding picture or diagram.

Answer (score 2):

The following picture is an example for an OR. Consider a token traveling from `Initial` to the `Choice` (diamond). Here the token travels either to the left or right guided by the constraints which test the condition checked in `Choice`. From then where they are they next transit through the following unnamed diamond to `Continued`. You might leave away the joining diamond and draw the transitions directly to `Continued`.

[image]

The AND condition looks like this:

[image]

The first `Fork`(the bar) duplicates the token and sends them to `Either` and `Or`. The `Join` behind these states waits for two tokens to arrive before it sends only one token further to `Continued`.

`Fork` and `Join` use the same symbol. They wait until **all** incoming tokens arrive and then send as many tokens as there are outgoing transitions. So they are actually some split personality. But mostly they are used the one or the other way.